# Robot doesn't move when on floor, wheels spin when off ground

Tags: pi-2

I have built a simple robot, my first project. When the wheels are off the ground, they spin, when they are on the floor they don't. At first I thought it was weight but it seems not, I tried removing all the components and holding them in my hand(with the cables still attached) so it was just a bare frame. I have 2 DC motors and 7 AA batteries. The Pi is powered separately. I used this tutorial

http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051

Below are some pictures. I realise you can't see the wiring too well, but i did it exactly as in the tutorial except the extra batteries

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but it sounds like the motors aren't getting enough power. Why are you using 7 batteries? The tutorial calls for 4. Please post some pictures of how you have everything wired.

Comment: @Jacobm001 because 4 wasn't enough I thought I'd try 7. They do spin very fast so i don't think thats the issue. I'll add some pictures now

Comment: Spinning fast does not mean they have the power to push under load.

Comment: @Jacobm001 true. ive added the pictures by the way

Comment: Have you tried this on a smooth surface like a tabletop or hardwood floor?

Comment: @Jacobm001 yes that is a tabletop. And i've tried on laminate flooring

Comment: Your motors don't have enough torque.

Comment: @SteveRobillard how much torque would i need?

Comment: I couldn't say without much more detail, but you may want to consider something like this (or at least the geared motors) https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13166 Also you may want to check the specs on the motors you have and the amperage/voltage you are sippplying them.

Comment: @SteveRobillard and that torque can be related to the current that is available to drive the motors - AA batteries are not THAT *powerful*  (except perhaps re-chargable based on a Nickel-Cadmium or -Hydride construction) - the Zinc-Chloride ones the OP shows being are the worse ones for this and they even say "for low power products" you may get better behaviour with *C* or *D* sized ones and, if you have to use primary cells (not rechargeable ones), try Alkaline ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those appear to be ungeared motors.  You need geared motors.

Can you stop the motor(s) turning by lightly holding the wheel with a finger?

When power is applied they will spin at something like 10 thousand RPM.  You need motors which are geared to spin at something like 50 to 150 RPM.

As mentioned in the comments there is not enough torque.  In your case torque is the ability to move the motor against a load.

Comment: Ah thanks. So is lower RPM better then?

Comment: @HamzahMalik Essential.  It will let your robot work.  100 RPM will work and move your robot at a foot a second, 10,000 RPM won't work as it tries to move your robot at 100 foot a second.  I'm using approximate figures, the actual depend on your wheel's size.

Comment: Ok thanks ill look into it. So geared motors at low speed of about 100rpm?

Comment: @HamzahMalik Yes.  There is no universal best RPM.  It depends on what your robot is doing.  Anything between 50-200 RPM is a good start.

Comment: You may want to read around robotic stack about a formula on how to calculate the correct gearbox setup. Motor to gear ratio and wheel radius. You may also want to use NiCD batteries or LiPO as they will last longer and allow for more power (amps) to be fed into the motors, also increasing output torque .

Comment: I ended up using geared motors and this fixed the problem even with lower power batteries (but only 4). With Duracell it worked even better